# Where are the "pin change" interrupts on the Arduino Uno?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I have been playing around with the Arduino recently (specifically the "30 Days Lost in Space" kit).  I am working with the encoder module.   I successfully connected both channels of the encoder pins to 2 and 3 and am able to generate interrupts to track the encoder, as pins 2 and 3 are mapped to interrupt 0 and 1 accordingly (and according to digitalPinToInterrupt() call.)  Other pins map to -1 with the same call.  I am trying to find out how to do a pin change interrupt for pins that are not 2 or 3 because there's supposed to be other interrupts specifically for pin change and not "external interrupts", but I can't manage to find samples that work for me.  I need help configuring "CHANGE" interrupt for other input pins than 2 or 3.

Comment: https://arduino.stackexchange.com

Comment: 1) you fail to mention what "work for me" means. 2) which examples have you tried? is the example or you the problem? all the examples I just checked looked ok. so it's probably you. no offense... as we don't know what you have tried we cannot tell you what the issue is. also Arduino does not support pin change interrupts to my knowledge so you'll have to manipulate the MCU registers directly at which point the Arduino world becomes kind of useless imho.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, Pin Change interrupts are not handled in the core library, so you have to deal with them at a lower level, as @Piglet mentioned might be a possibility.  I found [this example](https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/PinChangeInterrupt/) online which manipulates the proper registers and leaves it up to the user to add the appropriate ISR's for the pins used (there's a separate interrupt for each bank of 8 or so pins).

Here's are the pieces I needed to use, for example, pins 6 and 7:

```
#define ENC_CLK  6
#define ENC_DT   7

RotaryEncoder encoder = RotaryEncoder(ENC_DT, ENC_CLK, RotaryEncoder::LatchMode::FOUR3);

void pciSetup(byte pin)
{
    *digitalPinToPCMSK(pin) |= bit (digitalPinToPCMSKbit(pin));  // enable pin
    PCIFR  |= bit (digitalPinToPCICRbit(pin)); // clear any outstanding interrupt
    PCICR  |= bit (digitalPinToPCICRbit(pin)); // enable interrupt for the group
}
ISR (PCINT2_vect) // handle pin change interrupt for D0 to D7 here
 {
     encoder.tick();
 }  

void setup() {
//...
  pinMode(ENC_CLK, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(ENC_DT, INPUT_PULLUP);
// enable interrupt for pin...
  pciSetup(ENC_CLK);
  pciSetup(ENC_DT);

//...
}
```